# Why would supposedly different two event methods be called by the same object? (Mouse Click-Drag-Unclick)

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine, callback

**Version:** Unity3D 4.6.2f1

I have a grid of tiles (Cube `GameObject`s with a `Tile` script attached). They are positioned at their index location `[x][y] = (x, y, z=0) World Coordinates`.

I am trying to achieve a behavior similar to minesweepers: when the left click is released, unless there is a right click down, the tile upon which the mouse is released is revealed. Below, I try to get the coordinates of the tile upon which the mouse left click is released.

Before into code:

> - [**`OnMouseDown()`**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) -  OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the GUIElement or Collider.
> - [**`OnMouseUp()`**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html) - OnMouseUp is called when the user has released the mouse button.

Based on these definitions, *I assumed (mistake?) `OnMouseUp()` would be called by the object that above it, the mouse left click was released.*

On the `Tile` script, I have the following :

```
public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    // variables
    private Vector2 _gridPosition = Vector2.zero;

    public Vector2 GridPosition
    {
        get { return _gridPosition; }
        set { _gridPosition = value; }
    }

    // functions
    string Vec2toText(Vector2 v)
    {
        return String.Format("(" + v.x + ", " + v.y + ")");
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("TILE:: ON_MOUSE_DOWN:: " + Vec2toText(_gridPosition));
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        Debug.Log("TILE:: ON_MOUSE_UP:: " + Vec2toText(_gridPosition));
    }

    void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        Debug.Log("TILE:: MOUSE_ENTER: " + Vec2toText(_gridPosition));
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        Debug.Log("TILE:: MOUSE_EXIT: " + Vec2toText(_gridPosition));
    }
}
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwAAe.png) is the output:

```
TILE:: MOUSE_ENTER: (15, 15)
TILE:: MOUSE_DOWN: (15, 15)
TILE:: MOUSE_EXIT: (15, 15)
TILE:: MOUSE_ENTER: (14, 15)
TILE:: MOUSE_UP: (15, 15)    %% This line
TILE:: MOUSE_EXIT: (14, 15)
```

If I could get `(14,15)` on `OnMouseUp()` function, I'd directly find the tile to reveal but apparently I can't.  The workaround for my goal I thought was to keep a `static bool _isDragging` and use it in `OnMouseEnter()` in an `if` block to assign the tile to be revealed correctly. Is this -- calling two functions by the same object even though I pressed left click some object and released it on some other object? -- intended? Is there a better workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnMouseDown is only emitted for left mouse button. So you have to implement right click yourself.

One option would be to check for raycast as you press buttons.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        var ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
        {
            var myObject = hitInfo.collider.GetComponent<MyScriptOrSomething>();
            // Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

One other option would be using OnMouseEnter to check for right click. Something like:

```
void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

The reason OnMouseUp called for the tile you clicked is simple. This behaviour is the safest and more expected way most of the time. Think of mouse events of a gameobject as "user clicked on me" and "user released the button after clicked on me".

So let's say OnMouseUp is called for the object under the cursor at the time of mouse button release. Think of an operation that starts on mouse click and is going to be finalized when mouse button released (like drag and drop). Then you would painfully figure out that OnMouseUp will not be called if mouse no longer points to your initially clicked object. You won't be able to finalize the operation. You would have to catch mouse release event yourself.

In your case, OnMouseUp and OnMouseDown alone won't cover your needs. What you are trying to do is too specific to your application. Unfortunately Unity's input system does not cover this kind of interaction by default. Luckily Unity is flexible enough to implement this easily.

Comment: The problem is not about right click right now. See, the problem is here: Say Tile1(15,15) and Tile2(14,15). I left click on Tile1, drag the mouse to Tile2 and then release left click on Tile2, however the `OnMouseUp()` function is called for Tile1 even though mouse is hovering Tile2 when the left button is released. There is nothing about right button yet. The problem lies with the left click.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear about what I'm trying to say. I will update the answer right now.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is clearer now. I kept a static variable and handled things gracefully thanks to flexibility of Unity:)

Comment: In addition, there is another event called OnMouseUpAsButton. Maybe you would like to take a look at (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUpAsButton.html)

Comment: Your welcome. Have fun on your journey :) And visit us some time if you come to Ankara :)

Answer (score 0):

As a better workaround, instead of using a `static bool _isDragging`, use `void OnMouseOver()` function:

```
void OnMouseOver()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))  // left click released
        RevealTile();
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))  // right click released
        FlagTile();
}
```